# Populate data onto select tag(multiple) with data 'selected'

Tags: laravel-5.7

I'm making a project management system with Laravel 5.7 where I have my tables `User`, `Project`, `Project User` and `Task(not important here)`. I'm having difficulties 
trying to edit my `Project` data as each Project has many User(collaborator). My `Project User` table acts as a pivot table to store the many to many relationship.  All of the project `Edit` will be displayed in a bootstrap modal in a single page which i used a `foreach` loop to display all the data. **So my problem** now is I'm trying to load my data onto my multiple select tag while selecting the options that found.

Example User table has

```
James
Dexter
```

In project "A" the collaborator is

```
James
```

When i edit Project "A" the `select` input tag would set `James` with the `selected` attribute while `Dexter` would be "unselected". I have managed to populate the `User` name and set the `selected` attributes but due to some logically error, if I edit Project "A", it would set **both** `James` and `Dexter` as selected.

These are my tables

**User**

```
u_id PK
name
```

**Project**

```
p_id PK
p_name 
status (Active/Inactive)
type (Team/Personal)
```

**Project User**

```
pu_id PK
p_id FK of Project table
u_id FK of user table
```

**Project Controller(Index)**

```
//Get Team data based on project type and user id
$teamProject = DB::table('projects_users')
->join('projects','projects_users.p_id','=','projects.p_id')
->select('projects_users.*','projects.*')
->where('projects.type','=','Team')
->where('projects.status','=','Active')
->where('u_id','=',Auth::user()->u_id)
->get();


//Get all collaborator 
$allProjUser = DB::table('projects_users')
->join('projects','projects_users.p_id','=','projects.p_id')
->select('projects_users.*','projects.*')
->where('projects.type','=','Team')
->where('projects.status','=','Active')
->where('projects_users.role','=','Colab')
->get()->keyBy('u_id'); 

$allUser = User::where('u_id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

**Blade View**

```
@foreach ($teamProject as $proj)
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['ProjectController@update',$proj->p_id],'method' => 'POST'])!!}
    <!--Title-->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Project Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="title" class="form-control" id="p_name" name="p_name" placeholder="Title"
                value="{{$proj->p_name}}" required>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <!--Colaborator-->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Collaborator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select name="colab[]" id="colabEdit-{{$proj->p_id}}" placeholder="Select Your Member" required multiple>
                <option value="" disabled>Select Your Member</option>

                @foreach ($allUser as $user)
                     //Should validate if user exists in the project pivot table here             
                    @if ($allProjUser->has($user->u_id))
                        <option value="{{ $user->u_id }}" selected>{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @else
                        <option value="{{ $user->u_id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach 
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Any help would be appreciated and sorry if my sentence structure or english is unclear. Thank you

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work to pass your "selected" values in via the controller vs. trying to apply the logic in the view?

Making some assumptions about your project.

In your controllers 'edit' method...

```
$users = User::all();
$project = Project::findOrFail($id);

foreach ($project->user as $projectUser) {
    $selectedTags[] = $projectUser->id;
}
return view('edit', compact('project', 'users', 'selectedTags');
```

Then in your view...

```
<select multiple name="collaborators[]">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        @if (in_array($user->id, $selectedTags))
            <option selected value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Then in the 'store' method, delete from project_user where p_id = the ID of the project edited. Add a new record for each of the collaborators[] array.